# Converting a part of a field of a data frame to a lower case [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with the following:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(['DMA.CSV','NaN' , 'AEB.csv', 'Xy.PY'],columns=['File_Name'])
```

What is the efficient way to get all the File_Names with extension converted to lower case (excluding NaN).  The output should look like this:

```
['DMA.csv','NaN' , 'AEB.csv', 'Xy.py']
```

Answer (score 1):

This one excludes `'NaN'` from the output:

```
df = df.File_Name.iloc[df[~df.File_Name.str.contains('NaN')].index].str.split('.', expand=True)
df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1].str.lower()
df = df[0] + '.' + df[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
def lower_suffix(mystr):
    if '.' in mystr:
        return mystr[:mystr.rfind('.')]+mystr[mystr.rfind('.'):].lower()
    else:
        return mystr

df['File_Name'] = df['File_Name'].apply(lower_suffix)
print(df)
```

You are applying the function which finds, if it exists, the last '.' in your file name and replaces whatever comes afterwards by lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Using `os.path.splitext`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df=pd.DataFrame(['Hello.world.txt', 'DMA.CSV','NaN' , 'AEB.csv', 'Xy.PY'],columns=['File_Name'])
df["File_Name"] = [ filename+ext.lower() if ext else filename for filename,ext in df["File_Name"].apply(os.path.splitext) ]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
         File_Name
0  Hello.world.txt
1          DMA.csv
2              NaN
3          AEB.csv
4            Xy.py
```

Comment: Getting the error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not float...
Modified it as follows and it worked: df["File_name"] = [ filename+ext.lower() if ext else filename for filename,ext in df["File_name"].astype(str).apply(os.path.splitext) ]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(['DMA.CSV','NaN' , 'AEB.csv', 'Xy.PY'],columns=['File_Name'])
for i, v in enumerate(df['File_Name'].str.split('.')):
    if len(v) == 2:
        df.iloc[i] = v[0]+'.'+v[1].lower()
    else:
        df.iloc[i] = v[0]

print(df)

  File_Name
0   DMA.csv
1       NaN
2   AEB.csv
3     Xy.py
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I found the following method, which is quite simple, I feel:

```
df['File_Name'] = [x.rsplit('.',1)[0]+'.'+x.rsplit('.',1)[-1].lower() if '.' in str(x) 
   else x for x in df['File_Name']]
```

This will exclude all the NaN values and also will take care of multiple dots ('.') in the file names (as 'Hello.World.TXT')